# check box to activate/deactivate

Tags: jquery

I have the following code. I want to make a check box that will activate this code when checked and deactivates the code when unchecked. can someone show me how?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
function ()
{
$('#load_tweets').load('record_count.php').fadeIn("slow");
}, 10000); // refresh every 10000 milliseconds

<body>
<div id="load_tweets"> </div>
</body>

</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var refresh = function() { $('#load_tweets').load('record_count.php').fadeIn("slow"); };
refresh();

var auto_refresh = null;
$('#the-checkbox').change(function(ev) {
    if (auto_refresh) clearInterval(auto_refresh);
    auto_refresh = $(this).is(':checked') ? setInterval(refresh, 10000) : null;
});
```

Comment: Use `click()`, not `change()`, because the former always happens instantly, the latter only when the control loses focus.

Comment: @Tomalak, not true for checkboxes, according to the jquery docs: "For select boxes, checkboxes, and radio buttons, the event is fired immediately when the user makes a selection with the mouse, but for the other element types the event is deferred until the element loses focus."

Comment: @Ben Lee i got an error on this line `if ($(this).is(':checked') {`

Comment: @sarsar, oops, forgot a closing parens. Fixed.

Comment: @Ben Hmm maybe I got that mixed up. I just always use `click()` for these things, but I'll try to keep that in mind. :)

Comment: @Tomalak, I like to use `change` when possible because it sometimes catches keyboard events that `click` might miss. Or at least I convince myself that's the case -- I don't think I've actually read that anywhere. `click` very well may be equivalent in this context.

Comment: I've never managed *not* to trigger `click` when the control is interacted with, in my experience it's been reliable in all browsers and situations.

Comment: @Ben Lee thanks a bunch. Works great. Can I ask you for one more favor? Can you make it load some text to `#load_tweets` when the page initially loads? For example hello world

Comment: @sarsar, okay I modified it so it refreshes once immediately upon page load.

Comment: @Ben Lee I tried to add 2 instances of this code on one page, both with different ID's. When i check the boxes it doesnt do anything. When i refresh and only click one box it works. Is there a way to makes this work with multiple check boxes

Comment: @sarsar, would both instances load exactly the same data ("record_count.php")? What differs between the instances besides the checkbox id? P.S. I simplified the code a little bit.

Comment: @Ben Lee the only differences are the ID's and the php files. Here is the code i have before you made the update http://fixee.org/paste/obtpw9i/

Answer (score 2):

```
setInterval(function () {
  if ( $("#myCheckbox").is(":checked") ) {
    $('#load_tweets').load('record_count.php').fadeIn("slow");
  }
}, 10000); // refresh every 10000 milliseconds
```

Comment: This is an elegant solution if it covers the use case (and there's a good chance it does), but the timing will be a little different than what the OP literally asked for since the interval is always running. There is no starting/stopping it.

Comment: @Ben I thought about mentioning this, but then I figured that a 10 second refresh interval would indicate that timing is not a primary concern here. Then again, psychological effects are strong with stuff like this.